# How to send a random generated number along with email and password while logging in with laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I want to send a random generated number along with password and email field when the user is logging and attach that number where laravel is grabbing the user password (i want to attach the random number to the password that laravel grabs from the user table then check it against the password that the user entered in the login field)
However i am not able to send the random number from the login blade in a hidden field. Please help

Comment: please add your login form code so we can help you more.

Comment: It must me sent from the blade? could be generated in the controller that receives the data from the blade? (token, pass, username)

Comment: thank you for the reply.. I am hashing my password in eloquentuserprovide.php in its validateCredentials function. Here i am grabbing login form fields, hashing it and checking it against the password from database This is how i grab the login form fields in eloquentuserprovide.php:- $credentials['password'] and $credentials['email']. But when i add another field in my login blade file (say a hidden field with name="hidden" and value="somer_and_number") and i use $credentials['hidden'] in eloquentuserprovide.php. I get an error saying 'undefined index hidden'

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite default login function of laravel and create your own to send extra data after logging in.

Below is the code to get random number in session after logging in. Implement in your `Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php` .

```
class LoginController extends Controller 
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers {
        login as traitLogin
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $randomNumber = mt_rand();
        $request->session()->flash('random_number', $randomNumber);

        return $this->traitLogin($request);
    }
}
```

After that, if you wish to use it in `HomeController` then you can do as below,

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $request->session()->get('form_type');

        // the rest of your logic
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you want to use random number anywhere else, then you have to specify the   place where you want to use it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for the reply.. I am hashing my password in eloquentuserprovide.php in its validateCredentials function. Here i am grabbing login form fields, hashing it and checking it against the password from database This is how i grab the login form fields in eloquentuserprovide.php:- $credentials['password'] and $credentials['email']. But when i add another field in my login blade file (say a hidden field with name="hidden" and value="somer_and_number") and i use $credentials['hidden'] in eloquentuserprovide.php. I get an error saying 'undefined index hidden'

Comment: Can you please upload your code, so I can get clear idea about your query.